# AngularJS: $http response too slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using this code:

```
$http.get('/api/users').
success(function(data) {
    $scope.authors = data;
}).
error(function() {
    console.log('API error - config.')
});
```

And somewhere below (much bellow):

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.authors.length; i++) {
    ...
};
```

Sometimes it happens that `$scope.authors` are not avaliable yet. Is there any way to solve this?

*UPDATE*

This is the whole block structure:

```
// author

$http.get('/api/users').
success(function(data) {
    $scope.authors = data;
    processAuthors();
}).
error(function() {
    console.log('API error - config.')
});    

// if updating form

$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    if($routeParams.id) {

        $http.get('/api/offers/' + $routeParams.id).
        success(function(data) {

            // author

            function processAuthors() {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.authors.length; i++) {
                    if($scope.authors[i].email == data.author.email) {
                        $scope.author = $scope.authors[i];
                    };
                };                    
            }
```

Comment: Make sure not to call the function containing the for loop until the authors are available. $http is asynchronous. You can't expect the response to be there immediately. For more help, post a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

Put the loop in the succes part:

```
$http.get('/api/users').
success(function(data) {
    $scope.authors = data;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.authors.length; i++) {
       ...
   };
}).
error(function() {
    console.log('API error - config.')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it doesn't matter how much below it is - you still need to call it from inside the callback because it's an async call:

```
function processAuthors() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.authors.length; i++) {
      ...
    };
}
```

And then:

```
$http.get('/api/users').
success(function(data) {
    $scope.authors = data;
    processAuthors();
})
```

I used a function to make it look cleaner, but you can copy your code that depends on the callback inside it.

---

UPDATE

```
function processAuthors(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.authors.length; i++) {
                if($scope.authors[i].email == data.author.email) {
                    $scope.author = $scope.authors[i];
                };
            };                    
        }

$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    if($routeParams.id) {

        $http.get('/api/offers/' + $routeParams.id).
        success(function(data) {

            // author
            processAuthors(data);  // just call it here, define it outside
```

Comment: This solution is actually great because my code is really much bellow :)

Comment: Yeah, organizing code block into functions is always good.  But sometimes you just need to do a little hack and make it messy. :)

Comment: Indeed. Although my function processAuthors is inside $scope.on and $http.get and I am getting ReferenceError: processAuthors is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't have it inside another callback because of JS scopes - it won't be available outside that function. If you show me that whole block, I'll probably be able to fix it.

Comment: That block is really long. Where can I put it?

Comment: Update/add it to your question body. I just need to see the structure you have.

Comment: Updated. Please take a look.

Comment: Oh I see, you're actually defining the function there instead of calling it...  Note that I'm now passing `data` to the function (not sure if you need that).

Comment: I don't think this is right. You are referencing to data for offers, not for authors?

Comment: I'm giving you the ability to pass in whatever data you need. :) Your original code would process the offer data, though.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. This got complex. In my authors for each loop I need both of the data (one from $http authors, second from $http offers) :)

Comment: Yup, I've noticed that. :) You're getting yourself into trouble. You're welcome, sorry I couldn't help you more.

Comment: Probably. Maybe you could just modify the processAuthors function to accept two parameters, so you can pass in both the author data and the offer data... then inside it figure out what you need to build $scope.author.